# Birthday Coincidence Program c++

Tags: c++, loops

What's wrong with my code for this question?

Suppose that people enter an empty room until a pair of people share a birthday. Write a program BirthdayCoincidence to simulate one experiment. The output of this program is the number of people that were added until a pair had matching birthdays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
 using namespace std;

 int main(){
  srand(time(0));
  int year = 365;
  int people = 0;
  int daycnt = 0;

  bool found[year];

  while(daycnt<year){
    people++;
    int birthday = (int)(rand() % year+1);
    cout<<birthday<<endl;
    if (found[birthday] == true){
      daycnt++;
      cout<<people<<endl;
      break;}
    found[birthday] = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile your code with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: Another *paradox* is that a year does not have 365 days.  Four million people have February 29th as a birthday.

Comment: You're generating numbers between 1 and 365 (inclusive), and 365 is an invalid index for your array. Lose the `+ 1`.

Comment: `bool found[year];` is invalid C++ as `const` is missing for `year`.

Comment: @HansPassant That would be tricky to take into account. Maybe discarding 366 three times over four.

Comment: @Hans, do you mean twenty million people?  (* 4000000 365.25) gives only 1.4 billion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Bob__, it's easy enough: generate a random number in [0,1460] and then divide by 4.  The outcome `365` will occur ¼ as much as the other values (assuming you use a `std::uniform_distribution` to generate the numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the boolean array `found`. Accessing uninitialized variables will lead to undefined behavior.

You should do this:

```
bool found[year] = {false};
```

This will initialize all the members of the array to `false`.

variable length arrays are not part of the standard. While GCC supports them as extension, not every compiler does. So you should have a compile-time constant as the size of the array.

```
constexpr int year = 365;
```

Another source of undefined behavior is the following check:

```
if (found[birthday] == true)
```

Since `birthday` ranges from `1` to `365`, `found[365]` will cause an out of bounds access as the valid index range is from `0` to `364`. So you can use this check instead:

```
if (found[birthday-1] == true)
```

Comment: Technically you only need `bool found[year] = {};` to default initialise all members. Supplying the value `false` only affects the first member. Had you written `bool found[year] = {true};` then `found[0] == true` while the rest would be `false`.

Comment: Yes. I didn't want to explain value initialization, default initialization etc to a beginner.

Comment: I did this, but now there is an error in my output. it says "variable-sized object may not be initialized" for year

Comment: @FrancieAkins: It works for me. See this link: https://godbolt.org/z/bY7_Mw

Comment: @PW This construct `bool found[year];` is called a *variable length array* or VLA. VLAs are **not** legal C++, since in C++ the size of an array must be a constant. Some compilers allow them as an extension, but many compilers don't allow them at all. So I'm afraid it's tough to ask about them in a C++ forum since they aren't legal C++.

Comment: @PW The C++ way to write this code is to use a vector. `#include <vector>` then declare the vector as `std::vector<bool> found(year, false);` no other changes necessary to your code.

Comment: @john: I agree. Don't know what limitations the OP has. So I did not suggest vector.

Comment: @FrancieAkins: Looks like your compiler does not support VLAs. So you can have:  `constexpr int year = 365;` Updated the answer.